# Request for manually retagging 32 questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Currently 32 questions are [tagged with `retag` on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag), 30 of them with **only** this tag. Who would volunteer to manually retag some of them?

(I assume those questions ended up with this tag as a result of some automatic process(?).)

---

**Update**: Thanks to the volunteers the list above is now empty, but close votes were cast on these

- [1569687](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1569687)
- [1746768](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746768)
- [1746768](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746768)
- [1842535](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842535)
- [2145634](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2145634)
- [1965305](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1965305)

Comment: Did somebody already handle this?

Comment: Some of these look like more about programing practice/learning than coding. Shouldn't they be migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'll take a look as well. I also suggest to vote the closed ones for delete.

Comment: @Alejandro: that's currently not possible yet.

Comment: Definitely need a lot more close votes going on.

Comment: As of now, all those close candidates are already closed.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842535/printing-opcodes-to-a-file) is a bad question, but a real one... I think it is a wrong close reason.

Comment: The same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145634/how-to-learn-programming-languagesyntax-rules-etc-and-remembered-easily). This should be off topic, leaving a comment to ask that in [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I've retagged about 10 topics (most of them fall in `language-agnostic` category) and voted the closed ones for delete. Currently there's nothing left.

Answer (score 3):

Done, but BalusC was also taking care of some.